# Adding a specific part of a line to an array

Tags: java, arrays

My program takes in a file and adds specific parts of the file to different arrays. Here is my code:

```
public class GradeBookApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  String fileName = "";
  String name = "";
  char[] categoryCodes = new char[5];
  String[] categories = new String[5];
  double[] categoryWeights = new double[5];
  double[][] gradeTable;
  GradeBook myGB = new GradeBook (name, categoryCodes, 
     categories, categoryWeights);


  if (args.length > 0) {

     for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("File \"" + args[i] 
           + "\" read in and Gradebook object created.");

        fileName = args[i];
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        name = scanFile.nextLine();
        int numOfCodes = scanFile.nextLine();

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           categoryCodes = scanFile.nextLine().substring(0).toCharArray();
        }
     }
 }
```

And here is the file:

Student1
5
**a Activities 0.05

q Quizzes 0.10

p Projects 0.25

e Exams 0.30

f Final 0.30**
a100 a95 a100 a100 a100
q90 q80 q100 q80 q80 r90
p100 p95 p100 p85 p100
e77.5 e88
f92

I'm attempting to add the bolded code to separate arrays. The letter should go in categoryCodes, the word should go in categories, and the number should go into category weights. I've attempted adding the first part to it's respective array, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. Also, I'm unsure of how to add the second and third parts of those lines to the correct array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `split()` method.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       String[] all = scanFile.nextLine().split(" ");
       if(all.length == 3 && all[0].length() == 1 && all[2].matches("(\\d+\\.\\d+)")){
          categoryCodes[i] = all[0].charAt(0);
          categories[i] = all[1];
          categoryWeights[i] = Double.parseDouble(all[2]);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! The part for categoryCodes works perfectly, but the second two are printing out as [Ljava.lang.String;@7ea987ac and [D@7ea987ac. How can I fix this?

Comment: @me123 To view the arrays contains use this: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(categories));` do the same for  `categoryWeights`

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding 
if Input is :-

```
a Activities 0.05
```

assignment must be like:-

```
categoryCodes[0] = 'a';
categories[0] = "Activities";
categoryWeights[0] = 0.05;
```

now if index of `a, Activities, 0.05` is `0`, `1` and `2` in args array you can use

```
     for(int i = 0; i < arrg.length; i++){
        if(i %3 == 0){
             //this would be char a 
        }else if(i %3 == 1){
               // this would be your string part
        }else{
          //i %3 == 2 this would be your number part
        }
     }
```

You can use `switch` statement instead of `if else`.